# How to deploy an embedded server to Elastic-Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, embedded-jetty

We have developed multiple micro-services using DropWirzard to have embedded jetty servers for each micro-service.

Has anyone had experience with deploying an embedded server to elastic-beanstalk for auto-scaling?

*-Thanks for your time*

Comment: It looks like DropWizard just builds a war file. Have you tried just building a standard war and deploying it to beanstalk? Chances are it will work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll give them a try and see what works.  (Honestly didnt think about if DropWizard could be packaged as a WAR since it is uber-jar centric).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you consider deploying each micro service on a separate docker container and deploying these containers on AWS Elastic Beanstalk?
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_docker.html

Answer (score 3):

As of September 2015, Elastic Beanstalk supports plain Java SE environments for Java 7 and 8, so you can *"run any Java application, including those that use servers or frameworks such as Jetty or Play and are no longer restricted to using Tomcat as the application server for your Java applications" ([Java SE support announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/elastic-beanstalk-update-support-for-java-and-go/))*.

By default EB will start your application with `java -jar application_name.jar`.
Alternatively, you can include a *[Procfile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html#java-se-procfile)* within your application root, and specify exactly how to start it up with a `web:` directive on the first line:

```
web: java -Xms:256m -jar my_dropwizard_app.jar
```

Check the [latest EB developer guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-platform.html) for more detailed info.

Answer (score 0):

Create a zip containing your: application.jar, Procfile and config.yml

In Procfile write exatclty this: web: java -jar application.jar server config.yml

**Name the jar as application.jar**

Upoload zip on ELB.