# Elastic Beanstalk Embedded Jetty

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, embedded-jetty, microservices

I am building bunch of services with embedded jetty. I prefer to deploy those services in Elastic Beanstalk. Elastic Beanstalk supported environments comes with Tomcat which is not required for me. So which environment should I use to run my services in Elastic Beanstalk? I just need a bare-bone EC2 instance with Java and my embedded jetty application are capable to run in different ports. Is Docker container is the best way to run these services, even in that case i am not sure which environment should I use.

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deploy an embedded server to Elastic-Beanstalk?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120130/how-to-deploy-an-embedded-server-to-elastic-beanstalk)